# Four couples are seated opposite each other around a circular table. What is the correct number of arrangements?

Tags: combinatorics

The question is as above. Here is the direct quote from the paper this question is found in: "In how many ways could 4 couples (8 people) sit around a circular table, where each couple sit opposite each other"
The four multiple choice answers are:

(A)
1 way

(B)
72 ways

(C)
6 ways

(D)
24 ways

The answer given as correct in the marker's solutions is (c) 6 ways, I get a different amount using this python program:

```
lst = set()
for p in permutations('abcdefgh'):
    p = ''.join(p)
    if all(p[i::4] in ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh'] for i in range(4)):
        p = p[p.index('a'):] + p[:p.index('a')]
        lst.add(p)
print len(lst)
```

`len(lst)` is 24. To confuse the whole matter further, the answer suggested here: (www.careerbless.com/qna/discuss.php?questionid=530) as the answer to part (g) is 6*4*2 = 48, which I would totally agree with if it weren't for the result from the computer program. What is the true answer?

here is the set of solutions returned by the python program (`print lst`):

> set(['agecbhfd', 'ahfdbgec', 'agdfbhce', 'agfdbhec', 'aehdbfgc', 'afdhbecg', 'ahdfbgce', 'aechbfdg', 'afhdbegc', 'acfhbdeg', 'adhfbcge', 'aecgbfdh', 'acegbdfh', 'aegdbfhc', 'acehbdfg', 'agedbhfc', 'acgfbdhe', 'aedhbfcg', 'agcfbhde', 'aegcbfhd', 'achfbdge', 'agcebhdf', 'adfhbceg', 'acgebdhf'])

Comment: You don't allow for $ba$, $dc$, $fe$, or $hg$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not quite.  There's a rotation step that allows *some* of that, but it's incomplete.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Sure, but that rotation step just ensures $a$ is at the beginning. It doesn't fix the problem. (But it does explain why he gets $1/2$ rather than $1/16$ of the correct answers.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see what you mean.  It looks like the only difference in our explanations is the interpretation of "allow."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would agree with $48$.  As the table is circular, no seat is special, so seat the first woman and put her husband opposite.  That sets the orientation of the table.  You have six choices for the person to the woman's left, then four for the next seat, and finally two.  $6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2=48$  The official solution seems to ignore swapping husbands and wives, so you have three, then two, then one choices.

Comment: That's a programming question, about python, and an obscurely written python program. So this is probably the wrong place to ask why the program is wrong. @micsthepick

Comment: @micsthepick Your code does not produce, among others, the permutation 'adegbcfh'.  The only permutations you consider in which 'd' sits to the right of 'a' are derived from those in which 'b' is last.  Then 'a' is fourth, and the result of applying your algorithm is necessarily 'cgeadhfb', which is rotated to obtain 'adhfbcge', or 'cegadhfb', which is rotated to 'adfhbceg'.

Answer (score 1):

For ease in describing arrangements, I'll assume your program lists the positions of persons $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h$ in clockwise order starting
with person $a.$

If you examine the output of your program carefully, you should notice that there are $6$ arrangements listed with $c$ in the seat immediately clockwise from $a,$ but only $2$ arrangements listed with $d$ in that seat.
By symmetry, there should be the same number of arrangements for each.
Therefore we know your program is faulty.

If we drill down further into the program's output, we see that
the clockwise sequence $ace$ occurs twice but $acf$ occurs only once.
The arrangement $acfgbdeh$ is missing.

The reason for this is that the only arrangements your program will allow to
begin with $acf$ are derived from permutations of $abcdefgh$ in which $c$ occurs in the first half of the permutation (so that $d$ can be four places after it) and $f$ occurs in the second half (so that $e$ can be four places before it). This limits us to permutations of the form $??acf???$ (where each $?$ is substituted by a different letter), and inspection shows the only such permutation your program will count is $egacfhbd.$

You could fix the program by changing
`['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']` to 
`['ab', 'ba', 'cd', 'dc', 'ef', 'fe', 'gh', 'hg']`,
as previously hinted in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Playing devil's advocate here:

1. The table is circular. That suggests there is no difference between Couple A sitting at 0 and $\pi$ or at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, as long as the same couples sit to their right and left.
2. The question asks how many ways can four *couples* be arranged, not eight people. This could mean that Mrs. Smith or her husband can sit at any seat and they are considered the same arrangement.

With these (admittedly dubious) restrictions, after you seat the first couple, you have three choices, then two, and one: $3 \times 2 \times 1 =6$.

Comment: The OP assumes (1), actually. But (2) seems like a horrible meaning for the intended question. I'd be very irritated if that was what the question meant.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Agreed. I was just trying to figure out the assumptions that led to the answer being 6 and not 24 or even 48.